# Error token de acceso inválido en ZOOM

Tags: php, javascript

El problema consiste en que no puedo comunicarme con el servidor de ZOOM usando cURL, porque al momento de ejecutar el código este lanza el error:

> api_key=zo6vnIDiTD6sN2fuQ7hGrA&api_secret=Z9iiHMSL6CEt35IVk9Z3MDYP0jWKZRR&data_type=JSON&userId=profesor%40bitbcn.orgstring(46)
>   "{"code":124,"message":"Invalid access token."}"

Este mensaje lo obtengo después de aplicarle un `var_dump()` a mi `array` contenedora de la respuesta del servidor.

```
    function getGrabacionesZOOM(){
            $request_url = $this->url;

        /*Adds the Key, Secret, & Datatype to the passed array*/
        $data['api_key'] = $this->api_key_ZOOM;
        $data['api_secret'] = $this->api_secret_ZOOM;
        $data['data_type'] = 'JSON';
                $data['userId']= 'profesor@bitbcn.org';

        $postFields = http_build_query($data);
        /*Check to see queried fields*/
        /*Used for troubleshooting/debugging*/
        echo $postFields;

        /*Preparing Query...*/
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
        //variable contenedora de la respuesta
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        var_dump($response);
        curl_close($ch);

}
```

Este código debería de ser capaz de obtener esta respuesta para luego comenzar a parsear el `array`.

```
{
  "from": "string [date]",
  "to": "string [date]",
  "page_count": "integer",
  "page_size": "integer",
  "total_records": "integer",
  "next_page_token": "string",
  "meetings": [
    {
      "uuid": "string",
      "id": "string",
      "account_id": "string",
      "host_id": "string",
      "topic": "string",
      "start_time": "string [date-time]",
      "duration": "integer",
      "total_size": "string",
      "recording_count": "string",
      "recording_files": [
        {
          "id": "string",
          "meeting_id": "string",
          "recording_start": "string",
          "recording_end": "string",
          "file_type": "string",
          "file_size": "number",
          "play_url": "string",
          "download_url": "string",
          "status": "string",
          "deleted_time": "string",
          "recording_type": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Como lo indica la [documentación](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/cloud-recording/recordingslist) y la mayoría del código lo obtuve de un ejemplo de [github](https://github.com/zoom/sample-app-php)

Comment: Primero que nada ten en cuenta que el ejemplo de `github` esta **deprecado**, es decir, ya no sirve. Segundó, si prestas atención [en la documentación](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/guides/authorization/oauth-with-zoom) explican que debes obtener un `token` (_ver **Sample Node Request**_) el cual debes usar para poder consumir datos de todos los demás `endpoints`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en como estás haciendo la petición al servidor con cURL de PHP.

De hecho, la comunicación con el servidor de ZOOM es correcta, el problema es que no estás enviando los parámetros requeridos por ZOOM.

Según la documentación, debes enviar un token a través de los `headers` de la petición HTTP de la siguiente manera:

```
--header 'authorization: Bearer inserta_aqui_tu_token'
```

Y como parametro obligatorio por medio de la url debes enviar el `userId`

```
--url 'https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/inserta_aqui_tu_user_id/recordings'
```

Hay otros parametros, los cuales no son obligatorios pero podrías enviarlos por medio de la URL.

---

La petición que haces con cURL no está bien. En primera, en ningún momento mandas el token en los headers (ni siquiera mandas headers), y en segunda, me arriesgo a decir que el `userId` **no es** un correo.

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es conseguir tu token a través de una petición de tipo POST y así poder hacer más peticiones, [aquí en la documentación](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/guides/authorization/oauth-with-zoom) puedes encontrar como hacerlo.

Cuando hagas la petición para hacer el token, te retornara la siguiente información en formato JSON:

```
{
  "access_token": "5kwaMOrdEFWx1jYVK8qg80cImPYBA83Zff",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "refresh_token": "Ggf2816C5ANa6XVplzO8vwE6IRIXtjvE",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "scope": "meeting:write user:read recording:write webinar:write"
}
```

En este caso, lo que nos interesa es el **access_token**, una vez que lo tengamos, debemos de conseguir el **userId**, el ID de usuario lo puedes conseguir en la petición para obtener todos los usuarios llamada [list users](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/users/users).

List users nos retorna el siguiente formato JSON.

```
{
  "page_count": "integer",
  "page_number": "integer",
  "page_size": "integer",
  "total_records": "integer",
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "string", <-- Esto es lo que nos interesa tener para después
                          hacer la petición para obtener todos los recordings.
      "first_name": "string",
      "last_name": "string",
      "email": "string",
      "type": "integer",
      "pmi": "integer",
      "timezone": "string",
      "dept": "string",
      "created_at": "string [date-time]",
      "last_login_time": "string [date-time]",
      "last_client_version": "string",
      "group_ids": [
        "string"
      ],
      "im_group_ids": [
        "string"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Una vez teniendo el access_token y el userId, podemos hacer la petición para obtener las grabaciones de ese usuario mediante cURL de PHP.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

$user_id = "aquivamiuserid";
$access_token = "aquivamiaccess_token";

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/${user_id}/recordings?page_size=30&mc=false",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Bearer ${access_token}"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```